# affiliation or association (in the wording of the promotion help page)

Tags: discussion, help-center

There is a little discussion in the comments of [a recent MO question](https://mathoverflow.net/q/457111/11260) on the meaning of the word "affiliation" in our [promotion](https://mathoverflow.net/help/promotion) help page. If you promote one of your own publications in a post, should you disclose that you are the author? The help page says that "you must disclose your affiliation" if you promote something, but can you be "affiliated" to a publication? Perhaps "associated" would be better.

affiliated = connected to an organization
associated = connected to something

Comment: Just a note that this particular help page is universal on all Stack Exchange sites and cannot be edited by mods, only Community Managers. Thus it usually needs a very convincing reason to customize this page.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, in my view "your affiliation" here means "your affiliation with the product", in this case the paper.

"If you discuss a paper of yours, disclose that you are the author" is a good policy in my view.

I agree with you that the wording is confusing, given that "affiliation" is commonly used with another meaning in academia. And to back it up we have an actual example of a user that was confused by this wording.

We should suggest to change the wording on [meta.SE].

(Disclaimer: I am one of the parties in the little discussion mentioned in the question.)

Comment: Shortcuts such as `[meta.se]` work in comments and in chat - like here: [meta.se]. (They are called [magic links](https://meta.stackexchange.com/tags/magic-links/info).) But they do not work in posts.